# Python 2.7, Tkinter multiple choice quiz (notebook layout, and radio button help)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, radio-button, tk-toolkit

I'm a student, and as a beginner, I don't know much of Python. However, I decided to make a multiple choice quiz, in which no answer is incorrect, but all the answers add up to give you a total score. I have layed out each question page into its own class, like class Question1(tk.Frame):. Some of the code I used is from the help of the internet...

My first question is, how do I get each class to become its own frame (frame_1, frame_2, etc...) so I can use it in the Notebook layout?

My second question is, how do I get values from the radio button (value=1, etc...) to send to a possible .csv file to be stored? Nothing in my mind works...

Help would be highly appreciated!!!

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import Tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT= ("Arial", 12)

def sel():
            selection = "You selected " + str(var.get())
            label.config(text = selection)

#def answerout():

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar()
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
frame_1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame_2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame_3 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame_4 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(frame_1, text='Home')
notebook.add(frame_2, text='Question 1')
notebook.add(frame_3, text='Question 2')
notebook.add(frame_4, text='Question 3')
notebook.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

class Home(tk.Frame):
    frame1 = Frame(frame_1)
    frame1.pack(side=TOP)
    def __init__(root, parent, controller):
        frame1 = Frame(frame_1)
        frame1.pack(side=TOP)
        tk.Frame.__init__(root,parent)
        label = tk.Label(root, text="This program tries to understand characteristic features of individual students.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Please click start to begin!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button = tk.Button(root, text="Start!",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Question1))
        button.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Exit",
                            command=lambda: app.destroy())
        button2.pack()

class Question1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(root, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(root, parent)
        label1 = tk.Label(root, text="I make choices based on what I think, not on what I feel.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Not Often", variable=var, value=1,
                  command=sel)
        R1.pack( anchor = W )

        R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Sometimes", variable=var, value=2,
                  command=sel)
        R2.pack( anchor = W )

        R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Often", variable=var, value=3,
                  command=sel)
        R3.pack( anchor = W)
        button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Home))
        button1.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Next",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Question2))
        button2.pack()

class Question2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(root, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(root, parent)
        label = tk.Label(root, text="I challenge people if I don't think they are right.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        R4 = Radiobutton(root, text="Not Often", variable=var, value=1,
                  command=sel)
        R4.pack( anchor = W )

        R5 = Radiobutton(root, text="Sometimes", variable=var, value=2,
                  command=sel)
        R5.pack( anchor = W )

        R6 = Radiobutton(root, text="Often", variable=var, value=3,
                  command=sel)
        R6.pack( anchor = W)
        button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Back",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Question1))
        button2.pack()
        button3 = tk.Button(root, text="Next",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Question3))
        button3.pack()
        button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Home))
        button1.pack()

class Question3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(root, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(root, parent)
        label = tk.Label(root, text="I can change and fit into new situations easily.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        R7 = Radiobutton(root, text="Not Often", variable=var, value=1,
                  command=sel)
        R7.pack( anchor = W )

        R8 = Radiobutton(root, text="Sometimes", variable=var, value=2,
                  command=sel)
        R8.pack( anchor = W )

        R9 = Radiobutton(root, text="Often", variable=var, value=3,
                  command=sel)
        R9.pack( anchor = W)
        button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Back",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Question2))
        button2.pack()
        button3 = tk.Button(root, text="Next (GOES HP)",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Home))
        button3.pack()
        button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Home))

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
app = root
app.geometry('1024x512')
app.wm_title('Brain Thinking Model')
app.iconbitmap(r'fav.ico')
app.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is, how do I get each class to become its own frame (frame_1, frame_2, etc...) so I can use it in the Notebook layout?

There's not much you need to do to make each of the classes a notebook tab. You've already done most of the work. Your classes (`Home`, `Question1`, etc) are already frames, so you can use them directly. They each take a `controller` as an argument, so you need to create than, then instances of the class, and then add them to the notebook.

```
controller = <something you did not include in your question>

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
frame_1 = Home(notebook, controller)
frame_2 = Question1(notebook, controller)
...
notebook.add(frame_1, text="Home")
notebook.add(frame_2, text="Question 1")
...
```

> My second question is, how do I get values from the radio button (value=1, etc...) to send to a possible .csv file to be stored?

You need to have a reference to the variable associated with the radiobutton. With that, you can call the `get` method to get the value.

```
var = tk.IntVar()
...
R1 = Radiobutton(..., variable=var, value=1, ...)
...
value = var.get()
```

Since you are using classes, the best practice is to make `var` an instance variable. This means that instead of creating a global variable, you create it in the function that creates the radiobutton. You assign it to an instance variable, which you can then reference anywhere in your program that has a reference to the instance of the class.

```
class Home(...):
    def __init__(...):
        self.var = tk.IntVar()
        R1 = Radiobutton(..., variable=var, value=1, ...)
        ...

frame_1 = Home(...)
...
print("the value is:", frame_1.var.get())
```

Comment: What do I do to make a controller? I'm mostly lost already xD

Comment: @GauravKararia: I'm not sure. This is your code not mine. Maybe go back to wherever you copied the code from to see what it did to create a controller.